# .Net7.0 Project publish fails with IOException

Tags: c#, .net, linux, visual-studio, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a C# project I'm trying to build and publish for Linux-x64.
The build works in both debug and release for windows, but whenever i try building my program for Linux-x64 i get an IO-Exception:

```
>The "GenerateBundle" task failed unexpectedly.
>System.IO.IOException: A device attached to the system is not functioning.
```

None of my code even uses System.IO nor do any of my libraries. The build occasionally succeeds when i reboot my machine, or I keep my device manager open while building.

My publishing profile uses these settings:

```
Configuration: Release | Any CPU
Targt framework: net7.0
Deployment mode: Self-contained
Target runtime: linux-x64
Target location \\wsl.localhost\debian\home\myuser\output_folder

File publish options:
- produce single file
```

And my .csproj looks like this.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Terminal.Gui" Version="1.12.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I build my program on Visual Studio 2022 and I use debian on WSL2 to run my build.
Worth mentioning is also, that when my build & publish occasionally succeeds for the linux publish profile, i briefly get an update in my device manager window and the build works just fine.

I don't understand exactly why the build process (particularily within the publish process) needs any IO devices to be present.
Is there any explanation or remedy for this issue?

Comment: "I don't understand exactly why the build process (particularily within the publish process) needs any IO devices to be present" You have a build target where to put the build app. That's an IO device. I don't know to much about the specific build process but your target filesystem might have a problem.

Comment: It's WSL2, the filesystems should be compatible. Also, that doesn't explain why the build sometimes succeeds either.

Comment: It *is* compatible. You wouldn't use `\\wsl.localhost\debian\home\myuser\output_folder` from *inside* WSL though, you'd just use a local path, eg `dotnet publish ... -o ./output_folder`.  Are you trying to publish from Visual Studio into WSL?

Comment: Are you able to access the folders through Windows Explorer at all? Which Windows version are you using? There were [cross-FS problems in the past](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8170).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes. I'm trying to publish directly to WSL from VS. Thank you for this information! This helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

@PanagiotisKanavos above commented a reason/solution to this.
Publishinng directly from VisualStudio to WSL doesn't work. The publish path should be local to Windows and then afterwards sent to WSL.

Comment: It does work, unless there's a bug, but it's slow. An alternative is to keep the project files in WSL but still work with VS/VS Code. This is possible for quite some time now, using eg VS Code's [WSL extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl). [Dev Containers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers) take it farther, putting all the tools in a project-specific container (that runs on WSL).